# Array of images in google cloud machine learning

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a problem with importing numpy array to google cloud machine learning engine.

I'm doing this in that way:

```
X_test=StringIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(path+'X_test.npy'))
X_test=np.load(X_test)
print("loaded")
```

I'm trying to load 0.5GB npy file which cause this error:

> "The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 247."

This is my configuration:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: large_model
  workerType: complex_model_m
  runtimeVersion: "1.6"
```

Maybe am I doing something wrong in loading this array? Should I add some extra memory to deal with big arrays?

Answer (score 0):

If this was an out of memory issue after some time had passed, we could consider a memory leakage problem of the machine, and that could be attempted to be fixed.

However if is produced only when an array is loaded, the unique way to avoid the crash is increasing the memory.